# Adapting Shopping Cart Price Rules Magento CE 1.7

Tags: magento-community, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I need to set up a promotion such that if a customer spends at least $X, he can get one item from category Y free (the prices in category Y vary). When I set it up as follows:
Actions
Apply percent of product price discount
Discount Amount 100
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied to 1
Discount Qty step (buy x) 0
Apply to shipping amount No
Free Shipping for shipment with matching items
Stop Further Rules Processing No
If all of these conditions are true
Category is

Conditions
Subtotal in cart is greater than or equal to 125

I have also tried under Actions
It all of these conditions are true
Category is one of 
Quantity in cart is 1

When I do this and add multiple products from category Y, one of 2 things happens:
The coupon doesn't apply because there is more than 1 qualifying item (with Quantity in cart is 1)
The coupon discounts every item from category Y in the cart (instead of one free, they get a bunch)

Is there a way to make it so that the discount of the full price of only one item from category Y is applied to the cart? (Note: my interim solution is to use Fixed amount discount for the whole cart/is median value of product from category Y)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to consult the manual for more guidance: http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible by default rules types,  but you can add a new (custom) rule type, like "cheapest", "most expensive", "random", ect  and handle them via listening event `salesrule_validator_process`.

To add a new rule type listen for `adminhtml_block_salesrule_actions_prepareform` event and in your observer add a function like

```
public function handleFormCreation($observer)
{
    $actionsSelect = $observer->getForm()->getElement('simple_action');
    if ($actionsSelect){
        $actionsSelect->setValues(array_merge(
            $actionsSelect->getValues(), 
            $arrayWithNewTypesHere
        ));

    }
}
```

There are also ready to use solutions at the magento connect.